# Add Prime OS (Android_x86_x64) to grub menu

Tags: debian, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader, android

I have debian dual boot with windows and try to install prime os also,
while install it i didn't install it's grub because i have debian grub, 
but after installation i can't found it in grub .

result in `fdisk -l
/dev/sda2       112687104 133169151  20482048   9.8G 83 Linux`

i try to install grub-customizer and add it by code

```
set root='(hd0,2)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5d445e4-f59f-5158-b9c7-465f7009bc23
linux android/kernel root=UUID=e5d445e4-f59f-5158-b9c7-465f7009bc23 quiet      androidboot.hardware=generic_x86 SRC=/android acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode
initrd android/initrd.img
```

then it was added successfully but when i open it it's show

```
android/kernel not found
file located at partition `PrimeOS/android/kernel
```

[image: screenshot for partition details]
<sup>**partition details**</sup>

Answer (score 0):

from debian add the android entry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom

`menuentry 'Android' --class android  --class android-x86_64 --class gnu-linux --class os {
    set root='(hd0,2)'
    linux /android/kernel root=/dev/ram0 SERIAL=random logo.showlogo=1 androidboot.selinux=permissive quiet DATA= USB_DATA_PARTITION=1
    initrd /android/initrd.img
}`

update the grub

`sudo update-grub`

according to this configuration your android root dir should be "android" inside the hard drive

in other words you still on debian mount /dev/sda2 to /mnt and check what's inside
you should see "android" folder containing ( `data  initrd.img  kernel  ramdisk.img  system` ) ,

else you'll know what to do either rename your android root dir or deplace it depends on your case.

Comment: How to do that if you want to add PrimeOS and also Bliss OS?

Comment: just clone the same entry and change root=(hdX,Y) in case they are in different partitions , or just kernel & initrd paths , also menuentry name 
`menuentry 'PrimeOS' ....
menuentry 'BlissOS' ....
`
N.B: (hd0,2) means 2nd part on first hard drive

Comment: It's what I did. But only PrimeOS boots, and Bliss was booting before adding PrimeOS. It's like if only one could boot. https://superuser.com/questions/1549073/dual-boot-2-android-86-based-distro-bliss-os-and-primeos

Comment: something bugy there no mater what android os you chose in grub menu it'll boot the first found android os on the hard drive prime,bliss or any x_android .
you need a trick : post a question and provide more details ! if you don't get an answer i may do later cause i need to diagnostize that , there will be a solution.

Comment: Thank you Jonah!

Comment: I posted it here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225243/how-to-multiboot-2-android-x86-distro-for-instance-primeos-and-bliss-os

Comment: By the way, as you seem very knowledgeable about Android ISO and the boot process, I have a lot of problem to boot the Phoenix ISO https://superuser.com/questions/1546998/how-to-install-phoenix-os-from-linux

Comment: What does USB_DATA_PARTITION=1 ?

Comment: @Quidam i answered your question here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225243/how-to-multiboot-2-android-x86-distro-for-instance-primeos-and-bliss-os